# 301 редирект с динамической страницы /index.php?option=com_virtuemart

Tags: .htaccess

Как произвести настройку 301 серверного редиректа со страницы вида:

```
site.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart
```

на

```
site.ru/
```

используются:

```
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)  
Joomla! 2.5.10 Stable
```

Указанные ниже конструкции не работают:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_virtuemart$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\?(.*)$ $1\.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

пробовал настроить на `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_virtuemart$  
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://site.ru/ [L,R=301]
```

не работает

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо убрать query, то оставь вопросительный знак, если надо сохранить, убери.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_virtuemart
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению конструкция не работает.

Comment: Извини, переписал твой код невнимательно :) . Добавил звездочку в `(.*)\.php`

Comment: К сожалению добавление звездочки не помогло. Поправил в вопросе свои код.

Answer (score 0):

примерно так:

```
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_virtuemart$
rewriterule ^index.php$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

проверка. так перенаправляет:

```
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/index.php?option=com_virtuemart'
...
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: http://localhost/
...
```

а так — нет (добавил символ в конец *url-а*):

```
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/index.php?option=com_virtuemart1'
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

и так — нет (вместо `index.php` указал несуществующий `index1.php`):

```
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/index1.php?option=com_virtuemart'
...
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
...
```

---

если же требуется зависимость только от `QUERY_STRING` (то, что после символа `?`), т.е., чтобы в последнем из примеров тоже было перенаправление, вне зависимости от того, что идёт между именем сервера и знаком `?`, то `rewriterule` должно звучать примерно так:

```
rewriterule ^.*$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```